# Ubuntu 10.04/CURL: How do I fix/update the CA Bundle?

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I recently upgraded our server from 8.04 to 10.04, and all the software along with it.

From what I've found online, it seems that the new version of CURL doesn't include a CA bundle, and, as a result, fails to verify that the certificate of the server you're connecting to is signed by a valid authority.

The actual error is:

```
CURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:
certificate verify failed
```

Some palces I've found suggest manually specifying a CA file or disabling the check altogether by setting an option when you call CURL, but I'd much rather fix the issue globally, rather than having to modify each application's CURL calls.

Is there a way to fix CURL's CA problem server-wide so that all of the existing application code works as is without needing to be modified?

Answer (score 19):

I've been having the same trouble and after poking around a bit found that you can download a package of CA-certs ready for curl on ubuntu directly from the curl dev site.

```
cd /etc/ssl/certs
sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

Now curl uses the most up-to-date bundle and you're good to go.

Comment: after that i had to update with: update-ca-certificates -f

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar problem with **Ubuntu 12.04** running curl from the command line to get aws command-line tools which were in github.  I found if I ran the command-line as such:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/timkay/aws/master/aws -o aws --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

it would work. But trying to set the CURL_CA_BUNDLE environment variable so I could avoid the "cacert" argument would not work. Ultimately updating the ca-certificates seemed to resolve the problem:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

As a side note, at one point I updated ca-certs from curl.haxx.se which did not resolve the problem but may have been related. (`sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` run from `/etc/ssl/certs`).

Comment: Link 404'd for me. This works: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Hmm. Seems dodgy to fetch a file containing certs like that _not_ over HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, software that does not have a unique implementation and is compiled against OpenSSL will reference the system-wide ca-bundle.crt often located in `/usr/share/ssl/certs`.

The location may be different in Ubuntu but the OpenSSL package should include the ca-bundle file.

CURL has a variety of options to specify how it verifies certificates..

- The `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable for the location of the ca-bundle file.
- `--capath` allows you to specify the directory where CA certificates are located. (Overrides `CURL_CA_BUNDLE`)
- `--cacert` allows you to specify the CA certificate file.

On my CentOS server, I can run the following to identify the ca-bundle path that CURL uses:

```
$ curl-config --ca
/usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: Open SSL is installed. I have a "ca-certificates.crt" file in /etc/ssl/certs/ that looks like a bunch of certificates concatenated together, but I guess CURL isn't seeing it? Does CURL have a configuration setting for the CA-Bundle?

Comment: Are you sure it is not the type of certificate that it is attempting to verify?  Newer certificate technologies such as Extended Verification certs often require ca-bundle updates, as the root certs are relatively new.  Check out my upcoming edit too.

Comment: curl-config doesn't seem to be a valid command on Ubuntu. How do I set CURL_CA_BUNDLE?

Comment: Looks like it's part of the `libcurl3-openssl-dev` package based on a quick Internet search.  `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` is just an environment variable.  In bash, `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/file`.

Comment: Alright, package is installed, but "curl-config --ca" produces an empty line. I tried setting the variable using 'CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"'. But "curl-config --ca" still produces a blank line afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 10.04 lucid

put http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem into /usr/share/ca-certificates/
add a line

cacert.pem

into /etc/ca-certificates.conf

sudo update-ca-certificates

download the latest openssl and curl (configure with --with-openssl) make and install

it fixed my problem